# Save file name to database when using FileUpload helper

Tags: razor, file-upload, webmatrix

When using the FileUpload helper I am able to upload files to my folders however I don't know how to add the name of the file to the database for retrieval later on. Can somebody please help me? I have a database table I am saving to on this page already. I just dont know how to set the field "Resume" to the filename that it is supplied when uploading.

Code to save the file:

```
var fileName = "";
var fileSavePath = "";
var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];
fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/UploadedFiles/" + fileName);
uploadedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
```

HTML:

```
<label for="Image">Upload CV</label><br>    
    @FileUpload.GetHtml(
        initialNumberOfFiles:1,
        allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:false,
        includeFormTag:true,
        uploadText:"Upload")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the file name already via the `fileName` variable. Therefore all you need to do is pass that as parameter value to some SQL that inserts into the table:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO YourTable (Resume) VALUES (@0)";
db.Execute(sql, fileName);
```

For more on data access in ASP.NET Web Pages, refer here: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/data/5-working-with-data

Comment: Thanks Mike I will try that

Comment: Mike It did work for insert however I need it for an update to a table and its not working

Comment: You need to study the link I gave you. It covers very basic database operations including UPDATE statements.